# Materializecss' basic collapsible example does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

So, given this
html

```
    <!-- google fonts for material design icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
    <link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>  
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
      accordion : false // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
    });
});
```

extremely simple example which is provided in the materialize documentation, it just doesn't work for me... Can anyone point out anything obviously wrong? (I know there's no closing script and html tag, they wouldn't go into the code section for reasons I don't know)

When I click on one of the items I notice that it changes the ul id to "null"... what? And also, if you make a preselection by setting one of the collapsible header divs to "active" it works, but then you click on something else and it stops working again; something along the line is NOT setting the 'active' class to the correct elements...

Comment: I would suggest you to take `materialize.css` and `materialize.js` too from their site.. From browser console.. Paste the code in respective files and then check once again..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao downloaded latest materialize css and js files, restarted server/nginx etc. the code still does not work

Comment: No No.. don't go for latest.. Am saying go to **[`materializecss site`](http://materializecss.com/)** and from the browser console pick the `css` and `js` files.. Why am saying this is, what they have uploaded saying latest is not what they have in the above site.. Its still in development phase.. So get it this way..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao havent really found anything with that... too many files have been linked for me to know what they are explicitly using for the collapsible example, the script is also loaded externally somewhere, not as an inline script like I did, but I just don't know what. All of their files that are called materialize.css or materialise.js seem to be minified and dont have version information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what happened, but two days later, seemingly by random it begins to work, without any change to the site so... perhaps a cached file was outdated or something.